# vi is coded and I cannot read it

Tags: encryption, vi

I don't know why, but my vi editor seems to be encrypted. This is the test I ran.

```
gnome-open /usr/share/doc/xdemorse/examples/xdemorserc.example.gz
```

When I did this I could read it just fine. But then when I typed "vi" followed by the same file it is encrypted and I cannot read it at all.

Comment: Yes that was the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're opening  a compressed file. Vim in vi-mode doesn't support reading from compressed files, since this functionality is provided by plugins and plugins aren't enabled when in `vi`-mode (when `compatible` is set). Instead, try:

```
vim /usr/share/doc/xdemorse/examples/xdemorserc.example.gz
```

It might be the case that you have only `vim-tiny` installed. Install a more feature-complete version and then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```